# Проверка на существование переменной python

Tags: python

Есть у меня задание такого типа:

```
seven(times(five())) # must return 35
four(plus(nine())) # must return 13
```

В функции не передаётся никакого значения, но, по сути, для их взаимодействия я должен ввести какую-то общую переменную

Я так и сделал, создав строковую переменную, и возвращая её как результат
Но осталась проблема - при первом вызове функции мне нужно создать эту строковую переменную.

Могу ли я реализовать её создание таким образом:(дальше псевдокод)

```
if not variable.exist(): 
    string = ''
```

Как это можно описать в коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глобальные переменные - вообще очень скользкий инструмент, а в вашем случае можно легко обойтись без них:

```
def five(val=None):
    if val is None:
        return 5  # Если функция вызвана с пустыми скобками - просто возвращает 5
    else:
        # А если в скобках что-то было
        # То здесь выполняется какая-то другая логика с этим значением
```

Answer (score 4):

Вообще не понял задачи :) но псевдокод переводится в код вот так. Локальная переменная:

```
if 'variable' not in locals():
    variable = ''
```

Глобальная переменная:

```
if 'variable' not in globals():
        variable = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Так?:

```
import inspect


class ArithmeticFunc:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val

    def __add__(self, other):
        return type(self)(self._val + other._val)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return type(self)(self._val * other._val)

    def __call__(self, func=None):
        if func is None:
            return self
        return func(self)

    @classmethod
    def lookup(cls, name):
        mapping = {
            'four': 4,
            'five': 5,
            'seven': 7,
            'nine': 9,
        }
        try:
            num = mapping[name]
        except KeyError as ex:
            raise LookupError(ex)
        return cls(num)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._val)


def operator(func):
    def binded_to_first(first):
        def binded_to_second(second):
            return func(first, second)

        return binded_to_second

    return binded_to_first


def set_up():
    importer = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    importer.f_globals.update({
        'times': operator(lambda first, second: second * first),
        'plus': operator(lambda first, second: first + second)
    })
    for name in importer.f_code.co_names:
        if (
            (name in importer.f_globals)
            or (name in importer.f_locals)
            or (name in dir(__builtins__))
        ):
            continue
        try:
            importer.f_globals[name] = ArithmeticFunc.lookup(name)
        except LookupError:
            pass


def main():
    set_up()

    print(seven(times(five())))  # 35
    print(four(plus(nine())))  # 15


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```